# Wrong reference to Contacts table from sms inbox

Tags: android, message, android-contacts

I am trying to find the contact details corresponding to an sms from the phone's sms inbox. From my understanding the `person` column is a foreign key to the `_id` column of `ContactsContract.Contacts`.

My problem is that I am getting wrong values for the `person` value from the sms query. Some `person` ids don't exist in the contact table and some are pointing to totally different contact.

Below is the code that I use for fetching the list of `person` values, Can anyone tell me if I missed something or faced a similar problem.

Tested with Nexus S running Android 4.1.2

```
Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person" };
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(parsedUri, projection, null, null, null);

    Log.d(TAG, "Total Count " + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        // String address;
        int person;
        int personIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            do {
                person = cursor.getInt(personIndex);
                if (person > 0) {
                    // Add this id to a list
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Update: I was looking at some documentation from the `Android Developer Portal` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html), Is it possible that the `person` id that is retrieved from the sms inbox is referring to the `ContactsContract.RawContacts` instead of `ContactsContract.Contacts` as I have done.

Comment: You first check that person number is exits in contact list or not.if yes then match both id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the person column in the sms inbox refers to a `RawContacts` entry's id. By querying the  `RawContacts` table you can find the `contact_id` for the `Contacts` table for the specific user.

You can try this code to get the contact id from the RawContacts table..

```
long contactId = 0;
Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID };
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, 
        ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { rawContactId }, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int contactIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
    contactId = cursor.getLong(contactIdIndex);
}
cursor.close();
```

This should solve your problem for fetching the correct contact details by reading an sms row in Android. However as the sms data provider is not documented and phone manufacturers may use them differently, there is chance that this approach may not work on phones other than pure android.

Answer (score 0):

You first check that person number is exits in contact list or not.if yes then match both id.

```
Cursor cursor=managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
                        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
                                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
                        String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
                            // You know have the number so now query it like this
                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                    null, 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
                                    null, null); 
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                                String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
                                        phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));              
                            } 
                            phones.close(); 
                        } 
                    }
```